# Workspace ONE - 2 profile 2 extensions Chrome - macOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I'm trying to deploy 2 different profiles for 2 different extensions for Chrome, I'm using the key:

```
  <key>ExtensionInstallForcelist</key>
<array><string>ID;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx</string></array>
```

and

```
<key>ExtensionInstallForcelist</key>
<array><string>ID2;https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx</string></array>
```

But I think the key 'ExtensionInstallForcelist' overwrite any other profile with the same key, that's why I can't have 2 profiles with 2 different extensions, instead my pc is only installing one profile, so one extenions.
Do you know any way to deploy 2 different extensions? The groups are different, that's why I can add both extensions to the same profile
Regards.

Comment: What is “WS1”?  This sentence isn’t clear: “*But I this key overwrite the other profile and I can have only 1 profile installed.*”  Can you please clarify what you mean here?  Just a first look, if you’re trying to apply the same key, `ExtensionInstallForcelist` two different times, it will overwrite.  If you have two values for the same key, it needs to be an *array* of those values.

Comment: Hi Allan, sorry I though WS1 (Workspace ONE) was clear, as it's a known MDM. I have edited the description and the tittle.
I have 2 different profiles with the key `ExtensionInstallForcelist`, I have no problem if I use `ExtensionInstallForcelist` an then 2 arrays with 2 extensions, but I want to have 2 different profiles because the extensions are for different users and some of them can be on both groups or just one group.

Comment: It’s still not clear how those are two different profiles. It’s the exact same key and from what you”ve posted, it will be overwritten which is what you’re describing as happening. This appears to be more of an issue with profiles in Chrome rather than anything to do with macOS

Comment: I think is clear, in Workspace ONE, I have 2 profiles.
1 - Chrome Extension - uBlock
2 - Chrome Extension - Microsoft Editor

Both profiles have the key `ExtensionInstallForcelist` and I have opened this to see if someone can bring ideas or other way to do it.